# How to use fixed width in AT Panels everywhere (site template)?

Tags: theming, panels

I am using the [AT Panels Everywhere](https://www.drupal.org/project/at_panels_everywhere) theme and its ATPanels Everywhere Site Template. However, apparently it overrides the At panels everywhere theme because the width seems to be fluid and not fixed. How can I change the width to fixed? I tried it in admin/structure/pages/site_template and added css code but nothing changes. The site keeps it fluid width.

```
/* set a fixed overall width */
  #page-wrapper  {
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  /* Add some margin to the main content row. This class was set in the layout designer. */
  #page-wrapper .main-content {
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
```

The question is: How can I create a fixed width with AT panels everywhere site template?

Comment: I fixed formatting for you. Please be more specific than "any help?". Ask precise question, one that can have answer. Like "How to make X?" or "How to stop Y from happening?"

Comment: Please use [edit](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/163741/edit) to provide more information. This site is not a forum, comments are meant to be deleted as soon as they are no longer needed,

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer: look at default site template, copy-paste the css of the sample variant and set the page-wrapper.